# Trouble tokenising a string

Tags: c++

I am a beginner with C++ and am trying to tokenise a string such that `Tokenise("45+3") = {"45","+","3"}` Where the output is a vector, here is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector <string> Tockenise(string input){
    vector <string> Tocken_list;
    std::string previous_digit;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size();i++){
        if (isdigit(input[i])){
            previous_digit[i] = input[i];
        }
        else if (input[i] == '+'){
            Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
            for (int i =0; i < previous_digit.size(); i++){
                previous_digit[i] = 'N';
            }

            Tocken_list.push_back("+");
        }

        else if(input[i] == '-'){
            Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
            for (int i =0; i < previous_digit.size(); i++){
                previous_digit[i] = 'N';
            }

            Tocken_list.push_back("-");
        }
    }

}




int main(){

    vector <string> trial = Tockenise("45+3");
    for (int i=0;i < trial.size(); i++){
        cout << trial[i];
    }
    
}
```

The logic is to loop through the string, if it is a number concatenate it to the variable previous digit, if it is a plus or minus sign to append previous_digit to token_list and then append on the relevant sign.

When I try to run this I get the following error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Any ideas why? I thought it could be to do with me trying to modify string literals and I have played around with it for quite a while but cannot get it to work.

Edit: Got it to work with this:

```
vector <string> Tockenise(string input){
    vector <string> Tocken_list;
    std::string previous_digit = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= input.size();i++){
        if (isdigit(input[i])){
            previous_digit.push_back(input[i]);
        }
        else if (input[i] == '+'){
            Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
            previous_digit.clear();


            Tocken_list.push_back("+");
        }

        else if(input[i] == '-'){
            Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
            previous_digit.clear();

            Tocken_list.push_back("-");
        }

        else if(i == input.size()){
            Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
        }

        
    }

    return Tocken_list;

}

'''
```

Comment: @G.Sliepen I tried that and still get the same error, here is the modified code:   ```vector <string> Tockenise(string input){
 vector <string> Tocken_list;
 std::string previous_digit = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < input.size();i++){
  if (isdigit(input[i])){
   previous_digit.push_back(input[i]);
  }
  else if (input[i] == '+'){
   Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
   previous_digit.clear();


   Tocken_list.push_back("+");
  }
  else if(input[i] == '-'){
   Tocken_list.push_back(previous_digit);
   previous_digit.clear();
   Tocken_list.push_back("-");
  }
 }
}

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
previous_digit[i] = input[i];
```

`previous_digit` is of size 0 at that point. The subscript operator `[]` does not perform bounds check which is why you get a segfault instead of a well defined exception (accessing an out of bounds element).

You should use `std::string::push_back` to add an element to `previous_digit`.

Furthermore:

- you are missing a return statement.
- clearing `previous_digit` with `'N'` is... well it's terrible. Use `std::string::clear`.
- when you exit your `for` loop, `previous_digit` could hold a valid element which you will have to add to `Tocken_list` before returning it.

There could be other problems and the code could most definitely use a major rewrite. This is just what I caught very fast.

Comment: thank you all this insight really is useful, I especially agree with the clearing with N part. I have managed to get it to work now in a much less clumsily slapstick way.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code:

```
std::string previous_digit;

// ...
        previous_digit[i] = input[i];
```

Initially, `previous_digit` is an empty string. Subsequent code assigns something to `previous_digit[i]`.

The `[]` operator overload in `std::string` must reference ***an existing char*** in the string. It does not add characters to the string, it only accesses the existing ones.

Finally this function is declared to a return a vector, but is missing a `return` statement. This is also undefined behavior, and another bug that nearly always guarantees a crash.

You must fix both bugs. Additionally there are some other logical problems with the shown code, but these are the multiple reasons for undefined behavior, either one is likely to result in a crash.